# Nextjs 13 server actions and useState

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I'm using Nextjs 13 with server actions. I have a form:

```
const [isUploadingDocs, setIsUploadingDocs] = useState<boolean>(false);
... rest of code ...
return (
<form
  action={async (formData) => {
  setIsUploadingDocs(true)
  upload(formData).then((response) => {
  setIsUploadingDocs(false)
  })
}}>
)
```

I am never able to capture the state change within the above action. I've also tried `useRef`, and while that worked within the function, it did not trigger react's digest cycle, so my elements depending on the `ref.current` value were unchanged.

I read the documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/building-forms) and also tried `useFormStatus`, which also did not work as expected in my implementation. I'd rather just use `useState` if possible.

Is this a bug with nextjs 13 or expected?

Comment: Can you assign boolean value to your string type state?

Comment: I edited -- this was a bad copy and paste. the useState value is true/false, this is not the reason for the failure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is Nextjs context separation.

Server actions work inside server context, and 'client-only' features don't work inside server context. React hooks like `useState`, `useEffect`, `useMemo`, `useRouter`, etc. run inside client context only. I think [these docs may help you a bit](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns).

I also wrote a broad explanation of "client or server" separating behaviour. Maybe [that answer will help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77077564/9047572).

Comment: would it be the same answer if  say you were trying to pass state data into a server action function? I can access formdata but cant I get anything else ?

Comment: @aero8991 as I remember, yes. "formdata" feature is the only actual server-side feature that you can access from your client code directly. And that feature creates a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

In Next.js, the purpose of Server Actions is to handling forms in server components. Back in time, since Server Components only work if there is no interactivity it was way hard to make that and therefore they made this thing. UseState, useRef, useEffect and any sort of hooks similar to these which uses client's browser won't work with server actions.

The reason why ref.current was unchanged is not bug, since the formdata runs in server, it doesn't aware of the ref so you can't read it form there. You can't use useState either if you insist to use server actions.

I would recommend you to not use server actions if you need to display something in the inputs and show some clickable effects, since server actions are generally meant for api calls which shouldn't be bother user (analytics, user information etc.); However if you really want to use it, i would recommend [revalidateTag or revalidatePath](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/forms-and-mutations#revalidating-data), with this way if you place form actions in the respective manner, you can achieve what you want i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem and I've found the solution on https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/forms-and-mutations#displaying-loading-state

I think you should use 'onSubmit' event instead of 'action'  in <form onSubmit={onSubmit}...

Where the onSubmit function looks like below.

```
import { useState, FormEvent } from "react";
    
async function onSubmit(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
        event.preventDefault();
        setIsLoading(true); // Set loading to true when the request starts
        const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget); //get formData from event
        await action(formData); //Server action
        setIsLoading(false); // Set loading to false when the request completes
      }
```