# How can I use a react client sub-component inside a React Server Component?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, next.js13, react-server-components

I'm using Next.JS 13.4.19 with the new `app` folder to enable React Server Components, and running into issues trying to use **client** sub-components (i.e. `<ClientComponent.SubComponent \>`) inside a **server** component.

`ClientTest.jsx` is a Client component with sub-component attached (pretend this has some state or other reason to be client component)

```
'use client'

export default function ClientTest() {
  return <div>ClientTest</div>
}

ClientTest.Item = function ClientTestItem() {
  return <div>ClientTest.Item</div>
}
```

`page.jsx` is a React Server Component (allows access to db or file system)

```
import ClientTest from './ClientTest'

export default function Page() {
  // ClientTest.Item is undefined, and the following line errors with:
  // Unsupported Server Component type: undefined
  return (
    <ClientTest.Item />
  );
}
```

it seems the main component `<ClientTest />` works fine, but the attached `<ClientTest.Item />` is undefined :(

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/currying-grass-wsvtn4?file=/app/page.tsx

Possible workaround would be to simply avoid sub-components in the server compoonent by making another wrapper client component (importing ClientTest.Item in a client component works fine) but I would greatly prefer if this could be fixed through some magic webpack configuration? or maybe it's a bug in next.js?

For the record; Importing **server** sub-components in **server** components  works fine, as does importing **client** sub-components in **client** components.

**Edit:**

I am working on a component library which uses the sub-component pattern quite a bit, so it makes a big difference to me if this is a "working as intended" part-of-the-design of server components, or a "current implementation limitation"/bug.

If it is a *permanent* design limitation we might need to rethink our entire naming scheme and architecture to avoid terrible DX, but I haven't found anything conclusive about this in the react docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a better workaround for my case (as library author who needs to publish client sub-components exposed to server components), and posting it here in case someone stumbles across the same issue;

Instead of attaching the sub-component inside the component file with `use client`, I can attach and re-export in a separate file. Using an `index.js` file I can keep the import path the same for consumers, and since **this file does not have the 'use client' directive** it will be parsed properly when imported in a React Server Component:

`ClientTest/ClientTest.jsx`

```
'use client'

export default function ClientTest() {
  return <div>ClientTest</div>
}
```

`ClientTest/ClientTest.Item.jsx`

```
'use client'

export default function ClientTestItem() {
  return <div>ClientTest.Item</div>
}
```

`ClientTest/index.js` (note no `'use client'` in this file)

```
import ClientTest from "./ClientTest";
import ClientTestItem from "./ClientTest.Item";

ClientTest.Item = ClientTestItem

export default ClientTest
```

`page.jsx` is as before, but should now work fine

```
import ClientTest from './ClientTest' // now uses ClientTest/index.js

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <ClientTest.Item />
  );
}
```

Updated codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/eloquent-hooks-x3qgl8?file=/app/ClientTest/index.ts

Answer (score 0):

You do everything right, this is the Next.js problem. I just wrote a broad explanation of this behaviour. Please see
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77077564/9047572

TL:DR: you need that 'use client' directive to use client-only features. Once the component became client-side, its nested components are client-side too. No way to change or intercept this behavior.

Comment: Thank you for sharing! However it doesn't seem to be quite the same issue, I'm not *nesting* components, but rather attaching a component as a property of the exported component. Sub-component !== children, if that makes sense :)