# How to use Tailwind UI (headless ui) components with Next JS server components?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, tailwind-ui, headless-ui, react-server-components

I'm trying to build a web app on Next JS with Tailwind UI provided React components. [Tailwind UI](https://tailwindui.com/) is using [headless ui](https://headlessui.com/) behind the scenes.

By default, Next JS will build server side components, unless you add 'use client' at the top of a page. Unfortunately, this seems to be a requirement instead of an option in case of Tailwind UI provided code, otherwise it will throw an error like this on the picture.

[image]

So the question is, how to use Tailwind UI components (to move fast with the development without being a front-end genius), but still have the option to use server components with Next JS?

## What I tried

Tried using Tailwind UI components without 'use client', but they throw an error. Only solution is to add 'use client' at the top of the `.tsx` (or `.jsx`) file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do everything right, this is the Next.js problem. I just wrote a broad explanation of this behaviour. Please see
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77077564/9047572

TL:DR: you need that 'use client' directive to use client-only features. Once the component became client-side, its nested components are client-side too. No way to change or intercept this behavior.

And `TailwindCSS` use some client-only features. Your error tells the same. It tells that `headlessui.esm.js` is a client-only component, so you can use this library in client-side components only.

"Headless" doesn't mean it doesn't use some client-only bindings :)

P.S. Short list of "client-only" features. Basically Nextjs will show you them in its errors, but anyway...

- useX hooks from React and Nextjs: useEffect, useState, useContext, useRouter, useNavigation...
- quite everything from `react-dom`, cause there is no possibility of DOM manipulation on the server side
- browser event listeners like onChange.

You better read [the docs here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns)

P.P.S. Looks like there is another directory 'use server', which I didn't know of 2 days ago. [Worth checking](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering#network-boundary).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can I ask you to edit your answer and a brief list of those "client-only" features? I'm a senior engineer but quite noob when it comes to front-end, especially React and NextJS. I would use your list to research the docs, and research the headlessui files themselves, so that I can use the components more consciously, especially when building out their hierarchy